# List comprehension confusion

Tags: python

I'm slightly confused by a problem that I'm having and wondered if anyone could help (it seems trivial in my mind so I hope that it genuinely is!)

Basically, I have filtered by a list via the following list comprehension:

```
depfilt = [s for s in department if 'author' not in s]
```

(where department had 154 elements and the resulting depfilt has 72 elements)

Now, I also had a separate list of iD values with 154 elements (`subj`), for which the indices of this list match those in `department`. I wanted to retain the correct iD values after the filtering process so used the following line of code:

```
subfilt = [s for s in subj if 'author' not in department[subj.index(s)]]
```

In my mind, I feel this should've worked, but subfilt is actually returning 106 list elements, rather than 72.

Does anybody have any idea why?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `enumerate` instead of `index` in case of duplicate values

```
[s for i, s in enumerate(subj) if 'author' not in department[i]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If `department` and `subj` are definitely in the same order ie. corresponding elements of each match up, then use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over both lists simultaneously:

```
[(d, s) for d, s in zip(department, subject) if 'author' not in d]
```

(using `d` for department and `s` for subject).

And this way you don't need to reference each element by index. Just standard iteration.

Edit: If you want keep lists separate then you can do the first step for `dept` as you already have and then modify the second loop for subject like so, still filtering against 'author' while looping over both:

```
[s for d, s in zip(department, subject) if 'author' not in d]
```

(so the value of `d` is ignored in the 2nd loop)

Example of output:

```
>>> department = ['something', 'else', 'author', 'okay']
>>> subject = ['some_subj', 'else_subj', 'author_subj', 'okay_subj']
>>> [(d, s) for d, s in zip(department, subject) if 'author' not in d]
[('something', 'some_subj'), ('else', 'else_subj'), ('okay', 'okay_subj')]
>>>
>>> # and if you MUST do them seprately:
... [s for s in department if 'author' not in s]  # that's your `deepfilt`
['something', 'else', 'okay']
>>> [s for d, s in zip(department, subject) if 'author' not in d]  # this is for `subfilt`
['some_subj', 'else_subj', 'okay_subj']
```

Comment: What would the output be of this, would the lists remain separate?

Comment: Result of this would be getting a list with a tuple for `d` and `s` paired up.

Comment: I think the problem with this method for me is that I have to do further filtering of the lists, or is that relatively simple to do?

Comment: Edited my answer so that you still get two separate lists. Use your original first loop and the edited second loop.

Comment: If you are doing _further filtering_, then instead of two separate loops, do them together as per my original loop. That way each set of filtered items is grouped together in a tuple, which you can separate out later if you want. And you wouldn't have to keep repeating your filter conditions in different loops (error prone and ["DRY"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)).

Comment: Yes I think that may be easier and save me a lot of code in the process also, thanks!

Comment: This was my second filtering step relating to a department filter `depfilt`, how could this be done now that I've combined 4 lists together as tuples within a variable I've called `filt`:

`for t in depfilt:`
    
    `depfilt[depfilt.index(t)] = [d for d in t if 'affiliation' in d]`

Comment: If you're filtering on the same thing, then just add the other lists to `zip` for your filters. As long as it's the same filter across the lists. Like `[(d, s, x, y) for d, s, x, y in zip(department, subject, x_list, y_list) if 'author' not in d]`, etc. Anyway, this question's been asked and answered. If you have another one, maybe post a new question, this isn't really what the comments section is for.

Comment: So in this sense, I imagine it's easier to keep the lists as separate until all the filterin has been done and then group them together?

Comment: No, the other way round. If the filter is the same, keep them together.

Comment: Sorry, I think where I'm getting confused is that initially I filtered the department list 3 times, and then just wanted the corresponding indexes from the other lists at the end. So as it stands, I've filtered once so that I have a list full of tuples, but I'm confused about how to do the same filtering technique again when essentially this new filtered list is just _one list_ in itself